# Have issues with JDK Date / Time been fixed or is this considered still broken?

Tags: java, java-7, jodatime

For years there's been a consensus to use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or at least to not use the JDK classes ([Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), etc.) when working with dates and times, because the JDK components are broken.

Not to take anything away from Joda-Time, which I have used and can confirm is awesome, but I have to ask, did Java 7 in 2011 or any of its minor releases fix any of these problems?

I ask because all these years later there is a value in knowing if the JDK has been fixed and not making assumptions in either direction.

Comment: I have only been been programming for a few years but I have never had a problem.

Comment: Still broken, but Dates are fine as long as you don't try to do date arithmetic with them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### j.u.Date Deprecation

As stated in the [correct answer by Ryan Carlson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20809633/642706), some of the [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class' methods are deprecated but not the entire class.

Yes, you should certainly avoid the java.util.Date/Calendar classes except where required by other classes. They are badly designed and implemented. Try to do all your calculations and business logic using other, more competent libraries.

### Joda-Time

Currently, you should be using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3.

Quick example…

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

DateTime nowInParis = new DateTime( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) );
DateTime newDayInParis = nowInParis.plusDays( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "nowInParis: " + nowInParis );
System.out.println( "newDayInParis: " + newDayInParis );
```

Convert to [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)/GMT…

```java
System.out.println( "now in UTC: " + nowInParis.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC ) );
```

When run…

```
nowInParis: 2013-12-28T03:20:35.331+01:00
newDayInParis: 2013-12-29T00:00:00.000+01:00
now in UTC: 2013-12-28T02:20:35.331Z
```

### JSR 310

In the [near future](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/milestones), Java 8 will become available with a new set of [java.time.* classes](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) defined in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). These classes are inspired by Joda-Time but are entirely re-architected. The java.time classes have similar concepts to Joda-Time but you definitely need to do some re-learning.

- If available, **use Java 8**'s java.time classes.
  [Early releases of Java 8](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) are available.
  A back-port of these classes to Java 7 was begun, but I don't know the status.
- If not available use, **use Joda-Time**.
  Joda-Time is still actively supported and continues to work in Java 8 as well as Java 7, 6, and 5. For Java 4 you can use the very similar v1.x.

Here's a nice article explaining Java 8 java.time.* classes, [Java 101: The next generation: It's time for a change – Catching up with the Java Date and Time API](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078757/java-se/java-101--the-next-generation--it-s-time-for-a-change.html), by Jeff Friesen.

Comment: +1; I didn't know that about Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, they are still considered "broken". According to the [Java 7 API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/), most of `Date`'s constructors and methods are **`Deprecated.`**.

If I were you, I would continue to use JodaTime.

Answer (score 0):

They're still considered broken by most / many for anything other than simple tasks. In short, keep using Joda time.

As for them being fixed, the "fix" is Java 8's new time classes - these "fixes" will never be retrofitted to the date / calendar mechanism currently in use, since it would break backwards compatibility for applications relying on the current mechanism working the way it does (however odd that may seem to some!)